# LDFLAGS not being used

Tags: ios, gcc, arm

I have set LDFLAGS like this:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib"
```

but it seems it still only looks in /usr/lib/system

```
configure:2859: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2   -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: in /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib (2 slices) for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I set this the correct way???

Comment: I think you're missing a `-` since the option is `-L`.

Comment: Yeah, but that aint the problem I edited the text..

Comment: It's become more common to use gcc to link... have you tried putting the `-L` option in `CFLAGS` instead?